# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method

Tags: javascript

Работал на денвере на движке Word Press - слайдер работал отлично. 
Установил свой шаблон на сайт - слайдер выводит последнюю картинку, не изменяя ее, кнопки переключения слайдов - не выводит.

Отладчик Google Chrome выдает ошибку:

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'mobilyslider'`.
```

Языка и синтаксиса JavaScript я не знаю

Код двух js файлов:

**mobilyslider.js**:

```
(function($){$.fn.mobilyslider=function(options){var defaults={content:".sliderContent",children:"div",transition:"horizontal",animationSpeed:300,autoplay:false,autoplaySpeed:3000,pauseOnHover:false,bullets:true,arrows:true,arrowsHide:true,prev:"prev",next:"next",animationStart:function(){},animationComplete:function(){}};var sets=$.extend({},defaults,options);return this.each(function(){var $t=$(this),item=$t.children(sets.content).children(sets.children),l=item.length-1,w=item.width(),h=item.height(),step=0,play,bullets,arrows,z,active,bullet;var slider={init:function(){slider.data();if(sets.bullets){slider.bullets.create()}if(sets.arrows){slider.arrows.create()}if(sets.autoplay){slider.autoplay()}slider.triggers()},data:function(){item.each(function(i){$(this).css("z-index",-(i-l))});if(sets.transition=="fade"){item.hide().eq(0).show()}},zindex:{prev:function(){step==l?item.eq(0).css("z-index",l+3):item.css("z-index",l+1);item.eq(step).css("z-index",l+4).next(item).css("z-index",l+2)},next:function(){item.css("z-index",l+1).eq(step).css("z-index",l+3).prev(item).css("z-index",l+2)},bullets:function(){item.css("z-index",l+1).eq(active).css("z-index",l+2);item.eq(step).css("z-index",l+3)},trigger:function(){if(z==1){slider.zindex.next()}else{if(z==-1){slider.zindex.prev()}else{if(z==0){slider.zindex.bullets()}}}}},slide:{left:function(sign){sets.animationStart.call(this);item.stop(true, true).eq(step).animate({left:sign+"="+w},sets.animationSpeed,function(){slider.zindex.trigger()}).animate({left:0},sets.animationSpeed+200,function(){sets.animationComplete.call(this)})},top:function(sign){sets.animationStart.call(this);item.stop(true, true).eq(step).animate({top:sign+"="+h},sets.animationSpeed,function(){slider.zindex.trigger()}).animate({top:0},sets.animationSpeed+200,function(){sets.animationComplete.call(this)})},fade:function(){sets.animationStart.call(this);item.stop(true, true).fadeOut(sets.animationSpeed).eq(step).fadeIn(sets.animationSpeed,function(){sets.animationComplete.call(this)})}},animation:{previous:function(){step==0?step=l:step--;z=-1;switch(sets.transition){case"horizontal":slider.slide.left("-");break;case"vertical":slider.slide.top("+");break;case"fade":slider.slide.fade();break}},next:function(){step==l?step=0:step++;z=1;switch(sets.transition){case"horizontal":slider.slide.left("+");break;case"vertical":slider.slide.top("-");break;case"fade":slider.slide.fade();break}}},autoplay:function(){play=setInterval(function(){slider.animation.next();if(sets.bullets){setTimeout(function(){slider.bullets.update()},sets.animationSpeed+300)}},sets.autoplaySpeed)},pause:function(){clearInterval(play)},bullets:{create:function(){$t.append($("<div />").addClass("sliderBullets"));bullets=$t.find(".sliderBullets");for(i=0;i<=l;i++){bullets.append($("<a />").attr({href:"#",rel:i}).text(i))}},trigger:function(){bullet=bullets.find("a");bullet.eq(0).addClass("active");bullet.click(function(){var b=$(this),rel=b.attr("rel");active=bullet.filter(".active").attr("rel");step=rel;sign=rel>active?"+":"-";z=0;if(!b.hasClass("active")){switch(sets.transition){case"horizontal":slider.slide.left(sign);break;case"vertical":slider.slide.top(sign);break;case"fade":slider.slide.fade();break}}bullet.removeClass("active");b.addClass("active");return false})},update:function(){bullet.removeClass("active").eq(step).addClass("active")}},arrows:{create:function(){$t.append($("<div />").addClass("sliderArrows"));arrows=$t.find(".sliderArrows");arrows.append($("<a />").attr("href","#").addClass(sets.prev).text("Previous"));arrows.append($("<a />").attr("href","#").addClass(sets.next).text("Next"))},trigger:function(){arrows.find("."+sets.prev).click(function(){slider.animation.previous();if(sets.bullets){slider.bullets.update()}return false});arrows.find("."+sets.next).click(function(){slider.animation.next();if(sets.bullets){slider.bullets.update()}return false});if(sets.arrowsHide){arrows.hide();$t.hover(function(){arrows.show()},function(){arrows.hide()})}}},triggers:function(){if(sets.arrows){slider.arrows.trigger()}if(sets.bullets){slider.bullets.trigger()}if(sets.pauseOnHover){$t.hover(function(){slider.pause()},function(){slider.autoplay()})}}};slider.init()})}}(jQuery));
```

**init.js**

```
$(function(){
    $('.slider2').mobilyslider({
        transition: 'fade',
        animationSpeed: 800,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 7000,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        bullets: true,
        arrows: false
    }); 
});
```

Помогите разобраться, в чем проблема.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Рискну предположить, что init.js подключается перед mobilyslider.js

Comment: Нет, mobilyslider.js подключается раньше init.js

Answer (score 1):

Присоединяюсь к ReinRaus, скорее всего Вы подключаете init.js раньше mobyslider.js. Метод в этом файле через прототип определен, поэтому по идее не должно быть этой ошибки

Comment: Нет, в head я подключаю js скрипты следующим образом (mobilyslider, потом init):


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js""></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/mobilyslider.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/init.js"></script>

Comment: А элемент .slider2 на странице остался? Хорошо бы увидеть вживую пример, иначе сложно понять, в чём дело.

Comment: Да, класс .slider2 задан в блоке div.
Слайдер находится на сайте magnitiza.ru

Comment: Ура, заработало!
JS текст написан корректно.
Слайдер конфликтовал с одним из виджетов. Этот виджет повторно грузил библиотеку jQuery. Удавление строки с повторной загрузкой библиотеки позволило заработать слайдеру.
Большое спасибо всем откликнувшимся за помощь!)